# hashtag tagging document in SharePoint Online

Tags: sharepoint-online, taxonomy, term-set, tagging

I am a bit confused about hashtag tagging. Is it possible for user to be able to use hashtag to tag documents? I know how to use termset but I am not sure how to configure a site column to term store so the user can use # to tag any one word.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hashtags has been retired but still visible. Enterprise keywords is the preferred way.

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/add-an-enterprise-keywords-column-to-a-list-or-library-314ce556-e4bf-4ef7-9939-6a1bedfc434a

first go into the list or library and enable the enterprise key words column
[image]

then go into your term store from the admin centre to add terms in that you wish to use...direct link https://yousitehere-admin.sharepoint.com/_layouts/15/online/AdminHome.aspx#/termStoreAdminCenter

[image]

Comment: thank you. just what I was looking for

Comment: no probs happy to help

Answer (score 0):

Here're steps to tag documents:

1.Create terms in the Term store management.

2.In the terms usage settings -> Enable Available for Tagging.

3.Create a managed metadata column -> Use the newly created term in the managed metadata column.

4.In the managed metadata column -> Choose term to tag documents.